# How to show a video element when hovering over another div?

Tags: html, css

When hover over `.card` I want the `.video` to appear but it is not working. What do I need to change?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
    @media screen and (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
    html {
    scroll-behavior: auto;
    }
    }

/* header */


header {
    height: 509px;
}


header h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: 900;
}

header p {
    color: #ffffffb5;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

header a i  {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #ffffff87;
    transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

header a i:hover {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #ffffff;
}


/* header */
/* media query for header section */

@media (max-width:767px) {

    header video {
        display: none;
    }

    header {
        background: url(images/banner.jpg);
    }
    header h1 {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        font-weight: 900;
    }
    
    header p {
        color: #ffffffb5;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 1.7;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        
    }
    

    
}

/* media query for header section */

/* cards */ 
.cards {
    background-color: #202024;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.cards .video {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15%;
    left: 20%;
    display: none;
}
.cards .video .card:hover {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15%;
    left: 20%;
    display: block;
}
.cards .card {
    width: 30.3333%;
    background-color: #2C2C32;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}


.cards .card .image {
    width: 100%;
}

.cards .card .image img {
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.cards .card h2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 19px;
    padding: 23px;
}

.cards .card p {
    padding: 0 15px 30px;
    color: #ffffffa8;
    line-height: 1.3;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.cards .card .btn {
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.cards .card .btn button {
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #82CEC6;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 75%;
}
/* media query for cards section */

@media (max-width:767px) {
    .cards {
        padding: 30px;
    }

    .cards .card {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 35px;
    }

    
}

/* media query for cards section */
/* footer */

footer {
    background-color: #1B1B1F;
    color: #fff;
}

footer .container .upper h2 {
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

footer .container .upper p{
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    color: #a5a7a7;
}

footer .container .lower .icons i {
    color: #605d5da8;
    border: 1px solid #605d5da8;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 10px 30px 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .2s ease-in;

}

footer .container .lower .icons i:hover {
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #605d5da8;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 10px 30px 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

footer .container .lower .icons i:first-of-type {
    padding: 13px 16px;
}

footer .container .lower .icons i:not(:first-of-type){
    padding: 13px 13px; }



footer .container .lower .copyright {
    color: #a7a7a7a7;
}

/* footer */ 

/* media query for footer section */

@media (max-width:767px) {
    footer {
        padding: 20px 0;
    }
}

/* media query for footer section */


/*my frame work */

.flex-row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.flex-col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.float-l {
    float: left;
}

.container {
    padding: 5% 8% 5% 8%;
}

/*my frame work */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Motion</title>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/11e8366046.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="motion.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <!--Header-->
        <header class="flex-col" >
            <video src="images/banner.mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true" style="width: 100%;  z-index: -1000; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;  "></video>
            <div class="container">
                
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h1>Full Motion</h1>
                    <p>A responsive video gallery template with a functional lightbox <br>
                        designed by Templated and released under the Creative Commons License</p>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <a href="#cards" ><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-down"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!--Header-->    
        
        <!--cards-->
       <div class="cards text-center" id="cards">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="video"><iframe width="800" height="467" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/s6zR2T9vn2c" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
                <div class="card float-l">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="word">
                        <h2>Nascetur nunc varius commodo</h2>
                        <p>Interdum amet accumsan placerat commodo ut amet aliquam blandit nunc tempor lobortis nunc non. Mi accumsan.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn">
                        <button>Watch</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card float-l">
                    <div class="image">
                        
                       <img src="images/pic02.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="word">
                        <h2>Nascetur nunc varius commodo</h2>
                        <p>Interdum amet accumsan placerat commodo ut amet aliquam blandit nunc tempor lobortis nunc non. Mi accumsan.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn">
                       <button>Watch</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card float-l">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/pic03.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="word">
                        <h2>Nascetur nunc varius commodo</h2>
                        <p>Interdum amet accumsan placerat commodo ut amet aliquam blandit nunc tempor lobortis nunc non. Mi accumsan.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn">
                        <button>Watch</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card float-l">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/pic04.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="word">
                        <h2>Nascetur nunc varius commodo</h2>
                        <p>Interdum amet accumsan placerat commodo ut amet aliquam blandit nunc tempor lobortis nunc non. Mi accumsan.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn">
                        <button>Watch</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card float-l">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/pic05.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="word">
                        <h2>Nascetur nunc varius commodo</h2>
                        <p>Interdum amet accumsan placerat commodo ut amet aliquam blandit nunc tempor lobortis nunc non. Mi accumsan.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn">
                        <button>Watch</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card float-l">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/pic06.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="word">
                        <h2>Nascetur nunc varius commodo</h2>
                        <p>Interdum amet accumsan placerat commodo ut amet aliquam blandit nunc tempor lobortis nunc non. Mi accumsan.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn">
                        <button>Watch</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--cards-->
        <!--footer-->
        <footer class="text-center">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="upper ">
                    <h2>Etiam veroeros lorem</h2>
                    <p>Pellentesque eleifend malesuada efficitur. Curabitur volutpat dui mi, ac imperdiet dolor tinciduntnec. Ut <br>  erat lectus, dictum sit amet lectus a, aliquet rutrum mauris. Etiam nec lectus hendrerit , consectetur<br>  risus viverra, iaculis orci. Phasellus eu nibh ut mi luctus auctor. Donec sit amet dolor in diam feugiat <br> venenatis. </p>
                </div>
                <div class="lower ">
                    <div class="icons">
                        <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                        <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                        <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="copyright">&copy;<span>Untitled. Design: TEMPLATED. Images: Unsplash. Videos: Coverr.</span></div>
                    
                </div>
        </div> 
    </footer> 
        <!--footer-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is a better chance that you will get a high quality answer if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This question was edited to remove the question text that was replicated multiple times and make the title more descriptive. I'd suggest editing the code to only include the minimum code required to replicate the problem, as already mentioned in the other comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of: if you want to show any element (as well as a video) when hovering a card, then you need to put that element inside the HTML of the card. You failed to do that.

Also: you need to have the correct order of 'CSS selectors' to make that element visible when the `.card` gets hovered. Your original code `.cards .video .card:hover` fails to do that as it means: when from `.cards` and `.video` a `.card:hover` then show video.

What you need is: if from `.cards` a `card:hover` then show `.video`.

Also: when you want to position an element inside a parent you have to make `.parent { position: relative }` and its child `.child { position: absolute }`. Currently you use `.child { position: fixed }`. And without making the parent relative, the video is positioned somewhere on the screen (viewport) instead of the card (when all was working well, that is).

Lastly: the `<iframe>` you use is a child of `<div>` `.video`, so if you want to be able to size `.video` to your needs, you will need to make the `<iframe>` fully fill its parent (`.video`).

Plus: I changed the default `background-color` of the `<header>` to 'black' to make its content visible when there is no image.

To top it off: I added a `<a>` to the 'Watch'-button to open the movie on YouTube.

The below snippet has both the corrected HTML and proper CSS to show a video when the first card is hovered.

**Note** on SO the video in the card is still not visible, so I created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohdL1mn3/1/) to show that it works (**the first card only**, I leave the rest up to you).

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
@media screen and (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
    html {
        scroll-behavior: auto;
    }
}

/* header */


header {
    height: 509px;
    background-color: black;
}


header h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: 900;
}

header p {
    color: #ffffffb5;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.7;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

header a i  {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #ffffff87;
    transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

header a i:hover {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #ffffff;
}


/* header */
/* media query for header section */

@media (max-width:767px) {

    header video {
        display: none;
    }

    header {
        background-image: url(images/banner.jpg); /* MOD from 'background' */
        background-color: black;
    }
    header h1 {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        font-weight: 900;
    }
    
    header p {
        color: #ffffffb5;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 1.7;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
}

/* media query for header section */

/* cards */ 
.cards {
    background-color: #202024;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

/* REMOVE THIS CODE
.cards .video {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15%;
    left: 20%;
    display: none;
}
.cards .video .card:hover {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15%;
    left: 20%;
    display: block;
}
END REMOVE */

/* And ADD */
iframe {
    border: none;       /* remove default border */
    width: 100%;        /* stretch to fill parent container */
    height: 100%;
}
.cards .card {
    position: relative; /* child content must be positioned inside this */
                        /* => a new 'stacking context' */
}
.cards .card .video {
    display: none; /* hidden by default */
}

.cards .card:hover .video { /* when a card is hovered then show video */
    position: absolute; /* position this element within a 'relative' parent */
    top   : 0;          /* fully occupy the parent space */
    right : 0;
    left  : 0;
    bottom: 5rem;       /* up to some position above `watch` button */

    display: block; /* make it visible */
}
.cards .card .btn a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: currentColor
}
/* End ADD */


.cards .card {
    width: 30.3333%;
    background-color: #2C2C32;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.cards .card .image {
    width: 100%;
}

.cards .card .image img {
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.cards .card h2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 19px;
    padding: 23px;
}

.cards .card p {
    padding: 0 15px 30px;
    color: #ffffffa8;
    line-height: 1.3;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.cards .card .btn {
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.cards .card .btn button {
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #82CEC6;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 75%;
}
/* media query for cards section */

@media (max-width:767px) {
    .cards {
        padding: 30px;
    }

    .cards .card {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 35px;
    }
}

/* media query for cards section */
/* footer */

footer {
    background-color: #1B1B1F;
    color: #fff;
}

footer .container .upper h2 {
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

footer .container .upper p{
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    color: #a5a7a7;
}

footer .container .lower .icons i {
    color: #605d5da8;
    border: 1px solid #605d5da8;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 10px 30px 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .2s ease-in;

}

footer .container .lower .icons i:hover {
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #605d5da8;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 10px 30px 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

footer .container .lower .icons i:first-of-type {
    padding: 13px 16px;
}

footer .container .lower .icons i:not(:first-of-type){
    padding: 13px 13px; }



footer .container .lower .copyright {
    color: #a7a7a7a7;
}

/* footer */ 

/* media query for footer section */

@media (max-width:767px) {
    footer {
        padding: 20px 0;
    }
}

/* media query for footer section */


/*my frame work */

.flex-row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.flex-col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.float-l {
    float: left;
}

.container {
    padding: 5% 8% 5% 8%;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Motion</title>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/11e8366046.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="motion.css">
    </head>
    <body>

<!--Header-->
        <header class="flex-col" >
            <video src="images/banner.mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true" style="width: 100%;  z-index: -1000; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;  "></video>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h1>Full Motion</h1>
                    <p>A responsive video gallery template with a functional lightbox <br>
                        designed by Templated and released under the Creative Commons License</p>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <a href="#cards" ><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-down"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!--Header-->    
        
        <!--cards-->
       <div class="cards text-center" id="cards">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="card float-l">
                    <div class="video"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/s6zR2T9vn2c" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="word">
                        <h2>Nascetur nunc varius commodo</h2>
                        <p>Interdum amet accumsan placerat commodo ut amet aliquam blandit nunc tempor lobortis nunc non. Mi accumsan.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn">
                        <button><a rel="noopener" target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6zR2T9vn2c">Watch</a></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card float-l">
                    <div class="image">
                        
                       <img src="images/pic02.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="word">
                        <h2>Nascetur nunc varius commodo</h2>
                        <p>Interdum amet accumsan placerat commodo ut amet aliquam blandit nunc tempor lobortis nunc non. Mi accumsan.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn">
                       <button>Watch</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card float-l">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/pic03.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="word">
                        <h2>Nascetur nunc varius commodo</h2>
                        <p>Interdum amet accumsan placerat commodo ut amet aliquam blandit nunc tempor lobortis nunc non. Mi accumsan.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn">
                        <button>Watch</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card float-l">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/pic04.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="word">
                        <h2>Nascetur nunc varius commodo</h2>
                        <p>Interdum amet accumsan placerat commodo ut amet aliquam blandit nunc tempor lobortis nunc non. Mi accumsan.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn">
                        <button>Watch</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card float-l">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/pic05.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="word">
                        <h2>Nascetur nunc varius commodo</h2>
                        <p>Interdum amet accumsan placerat commodo ut amet aliquam blandit nunc tempor lobortis nunc non. Mi accumsan.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn">
                        <button>Watch</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card float-l">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="images/pic06.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="word">
                        <h2>Nascetur nunc varius commodo</h2>
                        <p>Interdum amet accumsan placerat commodo ut amet aliquam blandit nunc tempor lobortis nunc non. Mi accumsan.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn">
                        <button>Watch</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--cards-->
        <!--footer-->
        <footer class="text-center">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="upper ">
                    <h2>Etiam veroeros lorem</h2>
                    <p>Pellentesque eleifend malesuada efficitur. Curabitur volutpat dui mi, ac imperdiet dolor tinciduntnec. Ut <br>  erat lectus, dictum sit amet lectus a, aliquet rutrum mauris. Etiam nec lectus hendrerit , consectetur<br>  risus viverra, iaculis orci. Phasellus eu nibh ut mi luctus auctor. Donec sit amet dolor in diam feugiat <br> venenatis. </p>
                </div>
                <div class="lower ">
                    <div class="icons">
                        <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                        <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                        <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="copyright">&copy;<span>Untitled. Design: TEMPLATED. Images: Unsplash. Videos: Coverr.</span></div>
                    
                </div>
        </div> 
    </footer> 
        <!--footer-->
</body>
</html>
```